# Reviewing the questions by a reputed user before posting

Tags: feature-request

Is it right if I talk about a system where experienced users like somebody with 1000 points and above to review each question asked and make necessary suggestions as soon as possible and then post it.Also this should be done in a small time like 5 to 10 min.Which means questions should be posted however (unless its too pointless).

This would give the user(who asked the question) to make necessary suggestions as explained by experienced user.It would also reduce the discouragement from down voting(if any).If the questions are too pointless any experienced person can discard the question by giving a suitable reason and,automatically put the user who asked the question on ban for some 10 hours than banning for a big time (10 hours would be more than enough to discourage the user from asking pointless question).Only experienced users should be allowed to make suggestion at that small time provided.Only the experienced users should be granted access to this session.And the name of the user who asked this question should not be revealed to the experienced user.Any one experienced user should have all the rights to ban the question at his own consent.

Also the community must put this banned question publicly,it should be tagged separately, and let all users vote it,without considering their reputation.It is also worth mentioning that in this session the user who asked the question should be revealed.Users should not be allowed to make comments here.If the question is reasonable according to votes casted after a certain period of time then the same question should be posted quickly by somebody with reputation without altering it.(any suggestions if i am wrong?or if this idea is not at all fruitful)

Also if any other unwanted links are provided in the question,the user who asked the question must be banned immediately.And the question should not be put publicly for voting.

Comment: All first questions and answers already go through a review process. In this process necessary changes are made, comments and suggestions are issued. The tagging system is not designed for separating these questions out. Questions are not banned in any case, if they do not fit the standards of this site, they will be put on hold until they are improved. The system works reasonably well, and I assume there is no change necessary. How the community reacts to certain questions is a part of the whole process and I don't think there is much to improve.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン but is the review process done after posting the question or before that.

Comment: If its done after posting then chances of down voting are much.(Though down voting improves the quality of questions but i feel that sometimes its discouraging as well when reasons are not provided).

Comment: The review process is indeed done after the post is accessible on the site. IIRC there was a feature request about reviewing the questions before they go live, but that has the problem, that there needs to be a high rep user actually present and approving it. In some cases this can take very long. This is much more discouraging than a downvote. For example, when I sometimes come online there are 5 or more posts waiting in the queue. This might lead to users asking the same question over and over again, because it might appear that they have not succeeded in asking it in the first place.

Comment: How much does it make sense to speak to your teacher privately, explain your question to them in detail and tell them "this is my question. Should I ask it from you?"?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン yes you are right,sorry, i agree with your point that it would be time consuming.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン But will it be good enough if the questions gets automatically posted after sometime even if  edits are suggested or not suggested  by the experienced user (like setting a fixed time for suggestions).This too wouldn't make much sense if i am right.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? This is a Q/A platform, not an exhibition, not a personal tutoring service.

Comment: @IͶΔ I thought i had just commented  the same thing which Martin gave me a suggestion about.I didn't mean Martin was wrong.Thanks for the comment  IͶΔ .

Comment: Well, the thing is, this doesn't need a reason not to make sense. Cross site dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86466/proposal-for-limiting-mediocre-questions-unit-testing-for-questions

Comment: @IͶΔ didn't find that question earlier when i typed the header.

Comment: That's because it's in the mother meta ([meta.se]). Welcome to meta.chemistry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The biggest problems with this, in my opinion:

- What you're proposing is sheer charity. People are occasionally awesome, but I can't imagine a person that is *always* in a good mood and always charitable <sub><sub>Not even Mart</sub></sub>. Related to all the mentor thingy: [Opt in "mentor" privilege at 7.5k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254205/)
- What you're proposing is adding more complexity to this weird system, for not much of a difference: What **is** the big benefit in this, really? Downvotes aren't evil, they're just means of moderating the site.
- A good thing about SE is that you can ask your question right away: No complications, no stupid setups, no nothing. This hinders that.

And probably a couple of more pointers, which would come to you anyway after you see that it's not such a good idea.

Comment: I have patience, it is not infinite. You are right, not even me. Thanks for writing this up.